# how setup active_job and rescue scheduler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, rails-activejob, resque-scheduler, rails-4-2-1

I'm trying to create background jobs for email notification and scraper.
I use resque-scheduler (4.0.0), resque (1.25.2) and rails 4.2.1.

My config.ru file:

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment', __FILE__)
run Rails.application

require 'resque/server'  
run Rack::URLMap.new "/" => AppName::Application,  "/resque" => Resque::Server.new
```

My /lib/tasks/resque.rake:

```
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque/scheduler/tasks'

namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    require 'resque-scheduler'

    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")
    Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/jobs/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
  end
end
```

My /config/resque_scheduler.yml:

```
CheckFsUpdatesJob:
  queue: fs_updates
  every:
    - '1h'
    - :first_in: '10s'  
  class: CheckFsUpdatesJob
  args:
  description: scrape page
```

My /config/initializer/active_job.rb

```
ActiveJob::Base.queue_adapter = :resque
```

My /config/initializer/resque.rb:

```
#config/initializers/resque.rb
require 'resque-scheduler'
require 'resque/scheduler/server'

uri = URI.parse("redis://localhost:6379/")  
Resque.redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)

Resque.after_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }

Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/jobs/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'resque_schedule.yml'))

Resque::Server.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|
  user = 'admin'
  password = 'admin'
end
```

My first job for emails notifications:

```
class EmailNotificationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :email_notifications

  def perform(episode_id, email)
    NotificationMailer.new_record_appears(record_id, email).deliver_now
  end
end
```

My second job for scheduled runs:

```
class CheckFsUpdatesJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :fs_updates

  def perform()
    FsStrategy.new.check_for_updates
  end
end
```

So I have to jobs:
 1. emails notifications - should sends email when new record in DB appears
 2. scrape a page - should runs every hour

How I run it:

```
redis-server
rake environment resque:work QUEUE=fs_updates
rake environment resque:work QUEUE=email_notifications
rake environment resque:scheduler
rails s
```

After running these commands I see in Resque Dashboard two workers and two queues, as it is expected.

But!

After clicking on 'queue now' button at resque Schedule tab, I see that task was created and wroted to "fs_updates" queue. But it's not running and in a few second it dissapears.

When I run a job for emails sending from rails console - it does not work at all.

Please, help me to fix my configurations.
Thanks kindly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood: rails and active_job developers is not responsible for resque plugins. Maybe this problem will be fixed in new gem versions, but now it does not work (active_job does not work fine with resque-scheduler).

Currently I use `gem 'active_scheduler'` to fix current problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue trying to configure Sucker Punch on rails 4.2.1 In the end I moved my custom initialiser logic into application.rb, not great but it got me up and running.

Not sure if there is an issue with the initialisers in this release. Try moving your code from active_job.rb and resque.rb into application.rb or the appropriate environment file. Obviously this isn't a long term solution but it will at least help you you identify whether it's an initialiser issue or Resque config problem.